# JmsOutboundGateway - Java config missing options?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I am currently translating Springs XML- to Java-Configuration. (Spring Version 4.3.4) I'm currently struggling with Spring Integration. The JmsOutboundGateway seems not to support all options that are supported by its XML counterpart:

XML:

```
<int-jms:outbound-gateway 
  correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID" auto-startup="true" 
  connection-factory="connectionFactory" explicit-qos-enabled="true" 
  time-to-live="60000" request-channel="myRequestChannel" request-destination="outQueue"
  requires-reply="true" reply-channel="myResponseChannel" reply-destination="inQueue"
  receive-timeout="20000" >
</int-jms:outbound-gateway>
```

Translated Java:

```
@Bean
public JmsOutboundGateway myGateway(){
    JmsOutboundGateway gateway = new JmsOutboundGateway();
    gateway.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    gateway.setCorrelationKey("JMSCorrelationID");
    gateway.setReplyChannel(myResponseChannel());
    gateway.setReplyDestination(inQueue());
    gateway.setReceiveTimeout(20000);
    gateway.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
    gateway.setRequiresReply(true);
    gateway.setRequestDestination(outQueue())
    return gateway;
}
```

Namely **auto-startup** and **request-channel** seem to be "missing". Am I just looking for them at the wrong place or are additional steps needed? Have I even misunderstood something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All consuming endpoints created by the XML parser get 2 beans; a messsage handler and a consumer which invokes the handler; the consumer depends on the type of input channel; those attributes go on the consumer.

When configuring consuming endpoints using Java configuration, add `@ServiceActivator` to the `@Bean` to generate the consumer bean (use `inputChannel` for the request channel).

See [Programming Tips and Tricks](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   @Bean 
   @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="requestChannel",outputChannel="replyChannel",autoStartup="true")
     public JmsOutboundGateway jmsGateway(){
       JmsOutboundGateway gateway=new JmsOutboundGateway();
       gateway.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
       gateway.setRequestDestinationName("test.out");
       gateway.setReplyDestinationName("test.in");
       gateway.setCorrelationKey("JMSCorrelationID");
       return gateway;
     }
```

Comment: It seems, that you can set the replyChannel in the codepart `gateway.setReplyChannel(myResponseChannel());`